# Anylogic - Changing resource sets quantities via control edit box on startup

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm trying to adjust the number of resources needed before running a simulation by entering it on the start page.

This is what I currently have on my service block "activity1" in the main model:

[image]

This is what Im looking for to have as an input on my projects tab "Simulation:Main":

[image]

The custom resource set is more of a list and I cannot link the number of resources needed.
[image]

Comment: I tried using a function that will take input and output a string inside the resourcepool code field but I get "type mismatch: cannot convert from Sting to ResourcePool[]"

Comment: It looks like you can influence the number needed by the number of times you include the ressource pool in the list! So for having 3 apprentices, it would probabyl look like this: {{Electricians,Apprentice,Apprentice,Apprentice}}. You could use that and write a loop that fills a list with multiple entries of ressource pools, as needed.

Comment: @Florian Yes that is how it works. You unfortunately need to know Java for this: your resource sets for your block need to be defined via a function that returns a ResourcePool[][] (a 2-dimensional array of ResourcePool references).